# 2006 Ford F 150 5.4 Triton motor XLT Alternator No Charging

Tags: alternator, charging, voltage

I New Alternator New Fusible link and I still have low voltage battery light  in the dash that went away I have read a lot in I Can Find The problem HELP

Comment: What is the battery voltage with engine off? What is the battery voltage with engine at idle? Please measure both with a digital voltmeter and give the result with at least 1 decimal place.

Comment: engine off Reads 12.05 engine on is 12.85

Comment: Did this battery go completely dead or nearly dead before you changed the alternator? If so, it will take some time to get up to normal voltage. Best to put it on a charger until fully charged, then see if you're getting normal voltage (high 13 to low 14 volts) with the engine running. If no charger, idle for at least an hour or drive normally for 30 min or more.

Comment: yes it went dead  I took it to AutoZone and they did not charge it fully I try what you told me and get back to you Thank you

Comment: I took the battery to auto-zone the charge fully  But it still has low voltage 12.28  I'M Thinking computer but I don't know anybody who has the same issue

Comment: Okay the battery shows 12.85 when I start the truck, and the voltage goes down to 11.99 The engine sounds like it wants to die and starts charging up to 12.85/95 and goes down to 11.99/85 then charges again to 12.85 so I do t know if could be the battery.

Comment: You have a charging problem. I mentioned the 2 wires between the PCM and alternator, and there may be a problem with those which affects charging. You can test those wires for continuity end-to-end yourself, measure ground and control voltage and see how it affects charging. Or take it to a mechanic who knows how to diagnose charging problems. If their first step is to replace parts, they don't know how to diagnose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 3 fusible links in this vehicle.

18 ga brown on right side of engine compartment

12 ga gray at rear of engine compartment

12 ga gray on right side of engine compartment

All three of these are involved in charging, so make sure all three are good. Resistance end-to-end on each should be zero.

You have two wires that go from the alternator to the PCM. One is light green + orange which should be at ground voltage and the other is light green + red. This one is a control voltage sent by the PCM to regulate the alternator charging voltage. Both of these wires must be connected on both ends and intact and reading correct voltage for your charging system to work properly.

I don't know the correct voltage range for this light green + red wire. For a step-by-step procedure to diagnose your charging system yourself, you can subscribe to a service such as AllDataDIY.com, which will cost much less than replacing parts that might or might not be bad.